# Objective C: Array with size repopulate

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray

I need an array where I can store 3 values, and calculate the average of it. 
After 3s the array is full, I would like to refresh every value starting from begin [0] of the array. So every 3s the the array is updated and I have the most recent average. For the moment when I add an object the array keeps growing. 
This is the code I have at the moment:

```
//Inside function which loops every second so I can access myValue

self.myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
[self.myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myValue]];

for(int i = 0; i < self.myArray.count; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Array %d: %@", i, self.myArray[i]);
}
```

Output

```
Array 0: 2
Array 1: 4
Array 2: 5
Array 3: 6
Array 4: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if the size of your array is larger than 3. If so, remove the oldest element.

**Here is a possible implementation:**

Alloc and init the array:

```
self.myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Insert a new object and delete the oldest one:

```
[self.myArray insertObject:object atIndex:0];

if ( self.myArray.count > 3 )
{
   [self.myArray removeLastObject];
}
```

Comment: Hi,

Thx for answering! I already tried your example but then the first two values keep the same all the time. Do you know how to handle this?

Comment: That's strange. Are you sure that you are using `[self.myArray insertObject:object atIndex:0];` and `[self.myArray removeLastObject];` ?

Comment: Oh damn I forgot to add my object atIndex:0 ... Now it works! Thanks for helping me out and the quick response! Enjoy your weekend!

Comment: Excellent! You may accept the answer (click on the checkmark) and vote it up (click on the up-arrow) if it helped. Enjoy the weekend, too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to calculate a running average that gets updated every second. Here's a simple alternative approach that may work for you.

Initialize the average:

```
runningAverage = myValue;
```

Inside the loop:

```
const int WEIGHT = 3;
runningAverage = (runningAverage * (WEIGHT - 1) + myValue) / WEIGHT;
```

Here's what the output would look like:

Input: 1, 2, 3, 4, 101, 6, 7, 8

(Using an array)
Output: -, -, 2, 3, 36, 37, 38, 7

(Using running average)
Output: 1, 1.33, 1.88, 2.59, 35.4, 25.6, 19.4, 15.6